# OpenGL + SFML or SDL?

Tags: performance, opengl, sdl, sfml

Hey so i've just started SDL like a day ago, as i am planning on eventually stepping into OpenGL, but recently looked into SFML which is apparently more modern and easy. I have not heard anything or seen any books on it SFML, and i've heard people say OpenGL+ SDL is really good. **Is this also true for using SFML with OpenGL?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are programming in C++, use SFML. It will allow you to really use C++ features. If you are programming in C you should probably use SDL. They are similar in performance and functionality but SDL supports more platforms and is more popular.

Comment: Ok so what if i'm planning to use a 2d game engine such as LOVE2d, Exult, Flexible Isometric Free Engine, etc.. they also seem to have a very nice relationship specifically with SDL, but i have not heard anything about how they'll work with SFML.

Comment: I don't know these but after a quick googling, I think that these engines already pack the windowing/inputs/whatever you need, so I'm not sure why you would like to use SFML ?

Comment: You can still program in "C" with SFML - there are "C" bindings. They are not only important to "C" but to various dynamic languages, where reusing "C" sometimes is easier than "C++" - for example LuaJIT FFI, .NET, Python ctypes, etc.